# How to convert my xlsx sheet to java object using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

can any one suggest me to convert my xlsx sheet to java object using Apache POI.

eq, my excel sheet contains two columns

- emp_no   emp_name
- 01        anand
- 02        kumar

and my java object

```
Employee{
String empNo;
String empName; 
}
```

Now I want to convert my excel sheet to java object.
I have tried in internet but most of the tutorials talks about iterate each row and assign values to each member sin the object. Is there any functionality like Marshaller and UnMarshaller in JAXB xml parser which convert directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question. If you haven't tried anything at all, this isn't the place to ask for code.

Comment: hi Jonathan Drapeau, thanks for your replay actually I have tried with   lot of tutorial , all the tutorials are speaks about convert java object to excel I could not see about excel to java object thats the reason I have asked question here.

Comment: Have you found the answer? I wonder If you found mapper or how to map to object from Apache POI Row?

Comment: there is one framework for that called [Poiji](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji) using Apache POI internally

Comment: Check this repo : https://github.com/millij/poi-object-mapper

Answer (score 15):

For the given Scenario, I am assuming that each row of the sheet is representing an employee of which say first Column is keeping employee Number and second column is keeping Employee Name. so you can use the following:

```
Employee{
  String empNo;
  String empName; 
}
```

Create a method of assigning the Employee information as

```
assignEmployee(Row row){
    empNo = row.getCell(0).toString();
    empName = row.getCell(1).toString();
}
```

or if you want you can create a constructor for the same.

Now you just need to iterate over each row to get/use the information using the above method.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
       Row row = itr.next();
       emp.assignEmployee(row);
      //  enter code here for the rest operation
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Instead of iterating each row is there any way to convert,for eg JAXB we have concept called Unmarshaller ,marshaller which helps to convert object to xml and xml to object.Is there any kind of functionality available in Apache POI

Comment: What if i want to avoid iterating over empty rows in between excel data?

Comment: You can iterate over cell of particular row as well using row.cellIterator()

Answer (score 14):

Try this library internally using Apache POI for converting from excel to POJO.:
[Poji](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji)

Comment: Well maintained, good github starts over all posted libs here.

Answer (score 6):

Check the below repo. It was developed by keeping "ease of use" in head.
https://github.com/millij/poi-object-mapper

Initial version has been published to [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.millij/poi-object-mapper).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.millij</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-object-mapper</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Works similar to Jackson. Annotate your bean like below..

```
@Sheet
public class Employee {
    // Pick either field or its accessor methods to apply the Column mapping.
    ...
    @SheetColumn("Age")
    private Integer age;
    ...
    @SheetColumn("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    ...
}
```

And to read..

```
...
final File xlsxFile = new File("<path_to_file>");
final XlsReader reader = new XlsReader();
List<Employee> employees = reader.read(Employee.class, xlsxFile);
...
```

As it stands, all primitive data types are supported. Still working on adding support for `Date`, `Formula` etc..

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using POI and I'm uploading a simple program. Hope this will help you.

Note: Remember to change filepath.

Jars details: dom4j-1.6.1.jar, poi-3.9.jar,poi-ooxml-3.9.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

**My Data in Excel Table:**

```
ID   NAME  LASTNAME 
1.0  Ena   Rana 
2.0  Meena Hanly 
3.0  Tina  Mounce 
4.0  Dina  Cobain
```

**Model or Pojo: NewEmployee.java**

```
public class NewEmployee {
     private Double id;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;

     public NewEmployee(){}

    public NewEmployee(Double id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }    
}
```

**Main Method: ExcelToObject.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelToObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try
          {
              FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/ohelig/eclipse/New Worksheet.xlsx"));

              //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
              XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

              //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
              XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

              ArrayList<NewEmployee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    //I've Header and I'm ignoring header for that I've +1 in loop
              for(int i=sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
                  NewEmployee e= new NewEmployee();
                  Row ro=sheet.getRow(i);
                  for(int j=ro.getFirstCellNum();j<=ro.getLastCellNum();j++){
                      Cell ce = ro.getCell(j);
                    if(j==0){  
                        //If you have Header in text It'll throw exception because it won't get NumericValue
                        e.setId(ce.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                    if(j==1){
                        e.setFirstName(ce.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    if(j==2){
                        e.setLastName(ce.getStringCellValue());
                    }    
                  }
                  employeeList.add(e);
              }
              for(NewEmployee emp: employeeList){
                  System.out.println("ID:"+emp.getId()+" firstName:"+emp.getFirstName());
              }
              file.close();
          } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider to use this tiny library [excelorm](https://github.com/MrSkip/excelorm)

Answer (score 1):

Just found two libraries:

- `jxls-reader` (but configuration is done entirely in XML... ugh!!!) http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html
- `excel-object-mapping` this one is annotation only but unfortunately not really supported by its creator, e.g. still in "1.0-SNAPSHORT" or see the only pull request https://github.com/jittagornp/excel-object-mapping (Edit: repo has been removed since then, I found a clone here: https://github.com/pramoth/excel-object-mapping )

Hoping it'll help someone.

Comment: link to https://github.com/jittagornp/excel-object-mapping is broken :-(

Comment: yes, just saw that after someone tried to edit/update my comment to remove the "1.0-SNAPSHOT". in fact is seems the repo has been removed by its creator, but it has been cloned before here: https://github.com/pramoth/excel-object-mapping I'm pretty it's the same due to the nickname "na5cent" referred to in the original post: http://na5cent.blogspot.fr/2015/01/excel-object-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i've was aware that the implementation via the standard (Apache POI) why cost so much time so after searching and looking around, i have found a better why (JXLS-Reader)

first of all use/import/include the library jxls-reader

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

then create an XML file used by the library for the correspondence between the columns and the your object attributes, this XML take as parameter an initialized list to fill it by extracted data (Employee objects) from the Excel file, in your example, it will look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook>
    <worksheet idx="0">
        <section startRow="0" endRow="0" />
        <loop startRow="1" endRow="1" items="employeeList" var="employee" varType="com.department.Employee">
            <section startRow="1" endRow="1">
            <mapping row="1"  col="0">employee.empNo</mapping>
            <mapping row="1"  col="1">employee.empName</mapping>
            </section>
            <loopbreakcondition>
                <rowcheck offset="0">
                    <cellcheck offset="0"></cellcheck>
                </rowcheck>
            </loopbreakcondition>
        </loop>
    </worksheet>
</workbook>
```

Then in Java, initialize the list of the Employees (where the result of parsing will be included), then call the JXLS reader by the input Excel file and the XML mapping, it will look like:

```java
package com.department;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.jxls.reader.ReaderBuilder;
import org.jxls.reader.ReaderConfig;
import org.jxls.reader.XLSReader;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class ExcelProcessor {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelProcessor.class);

    public void parseExcelFile(File excelFile) throws Exception{
        final List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        InputStream xmlMapping = new BufferedInputStream(ExcelProcessor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("proBroMapping.xml"));
        ReaderConfig.getInstance().setUseDefaultValuesForPrimitiveTypes(true);
        ReaderConfig.getInstance().setSkipErrors(true);
        InputStream inputXLS;
        try{
            XLSReader mainReader = ReaderBuilder.buildFromXML(xmlMapping);
            inputXLS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(excelFile));
            final Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            beans.put("employeeList", employeeList);
            mainReader.read(inputXLS, beans);
            System.out.println("Employee data are extracted successfully from the Excel file, number of Employees is: "+employeeList.size());
        } catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ex){
            // Case of a very large file that exceed the capacity of the physical memory
               ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps anyone having such a problem !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find a simple way to parse a xls/xlsx file to a list of pojo. After some searching i didn't find anything convenient and preferred to develop it quickly. Now i am able to get pojos by simply calling :

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ExcelUtilsTest.xlsx");
List<Pojo> pojos = ExcelToPojoUtils.toPojo(Pojo.class, is);
```

If interested take a look on it :

https://github.com/ZPavel/excelToPojo

Answer (score 0):

Set a look on that [example](https://gitlab.com/mawwaad/xlsx_to_objects_example/-/tree/master) that uses Apache POI to bind xlsx sheet to list of objects.

It is a very simple example to show how to convert Microsoft Excel (xlsx) sheet to list of objects using Apache POI.

The idea is simply to define annotation @ExcelCellInfo on the fields you want to map the sheet columns to. Then the sheet cells will be bound using reflection according to annotation attributes.

Usage example:

```
ExcelSheetDescriptor<RowClassSample> sheetDescriptor = new ExcelSheetDescriptor<>(RowClassSample.class).setHasHeader();
List<RowClassSample> rows = ExcelUtils.readFirstSheet("pathToFile.xlsx", sheetDescriptor);
```

And the class to bind to:

```
public class RowClassSample {

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 0)
    private long serial;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 1)
    private String name;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 2, cellParser = CellNumericAsStringParser.class)
    private String registrationNumber;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 3, cellParser = CellPercentageParser.class)
    private Double percentage;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 6)
    private String reason;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 4)
    private String notes;

    @ExcelCellInfo(index = 5, cellParser = CellBooleanYesNoArParser.class)
    private boolean approval;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)