# Create object from Excel using Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create Object from Excel. The excel file looks like this
[image]

I am trying to follow this idea from this post [How to convert my xlsx sheet to java object using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015660/how-to-convert-my-xlsx-sheet-to-java-object-using-apache-poi). The very 1st answer looks good. However I am little lost on the part on how to create the object.

```
public class Tr {

    String empName;
    String empID;
    String empDept;

    //Constructor
    public Tr(String empName, String empID, String empDept) {
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empID = empID;
        this.empDept = empDept;
    }

    //The following part will  read Excel and return cell data
    public static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> deptId = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> dName = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getCellData(int cellNo) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\MyTemp\\People.xlsx");
        HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheet("Sheet1");
        Iterator<Row> it = sheet.iterator();

        ArrayList<String> cellData = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            cellData.add(it.next().getCell(cellNo).getStringCellValue());
        }
        return cellData;
    }

    //Assigning cell data to variables and converting to string 
    public void assignEmployee() throws IOException {
        empName = getCellData(0).toString();
        empID = getCellData(1).toString();
        empDept = getCellData(2).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Your help or ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked to doesn't quite do it this way.  That answer suggests you should load the excel file once, and then iterate each `Row` in order to assign it to an `Employee` instance.

So basic usage would be like:

```
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\MyTemp\\People.xlsx");
    HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheet("Sheet1");

    Iterator<Row> it = sheet.iterator();
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Row row = itr.next();
        emp.assignEmployee(row);
        //  use emp instance here
    }
```

In other words, the class `Employee` would look like this:

```
public class Employee{
    private String empNo;
    private String empName; 

    public void assignEmployee(Row row) {
        empNo = row.getCell(0).toString();
        empName = row.getCell(1).toString();
    }
}
```

From here, you use the instance of `Employee` for whatever scope you require.  I would personally go one step further and do the assigning in the constructor of `Employee` rather than have a method called `assignEmployee` (which like this may create problems with threads).

```
    Iterator<Row> it = sheet.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Row row = itr.next();
        Employee emp = new Employee(row);

        //  use emp instance here
    }
```